# VueJS slots with v-for loop do not display proper elements

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I'm trying to create a component that displays a subset of items passed to it.

So far I have a 'sublist' component with named slots as follows:

```
 ...
 data: () => ({
    startItem : 0
 })
 ...
<template>
    <div>
        <slot v-for="ctr in maxItems" :name="'s-' + (ctr + startItem - 1)"></slot>
    </div>
</template>
```

In the parent I do the following:

```
<sublist :max-items="5">
   <div v-for="(i,index) in items" :slot="'s-'+index">
      {{index}}
   </div>
</sublist>
```

When it loads, everything renders fine:

`0 1 2 3 4`

However when I increment `startItem` in the `sublist` component, the output becomes:

`5 1 2 3 4`

So it removes the 0th slot and stuffs slot 5 in its place. What is a proper way to replace the slots or make them "dynamic"? I'm using VueJS 2.4.2

Comment: Try adding unique **key** attributes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @SteveHolgado I found the answer: had to add `:key` attribute in the parent `v-for` and wrap each `slot` in the child in its own div:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <div v-for="ctr in maxItems">
            <slot :name="'s-' + (ctr + startItem - 1)"></slot>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```